# How to launch an inbuild app like(Any feature from settings of the device) with the current activity using the appium driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-java

When I am launching an inbuild app in Android. It navigates to the home page of that application. I want to open the current activity of that application and perform some automation in that page. Is this possible?

I tried with different methods to launch the app with current activity. But unable to get it. Its navigating to home page when launching the app. I am expecting like is there any way like to set any preferred capabilities to launch the inbuild app in Android with current activity?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "appium:app" capability to launch the app, use "appium:appPackage" and "appium:appActivity" to launch specific activity of the app. You can use apps like "Apkinfo" to get the name of activities of the app and provide the desire activity for "appium:appActivity" capcability. Refer the below code snippet for Android App:

```
UiAutomator2Options op = new UiAutomator2Options();

op.setCapability("appPackage", app_package_name);
op.setCapability("appActivity", app_activity_name);
```

For more details you can refer the documentation available here:
https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#app